# Pagefile system managed size not sticking

Tags: windows-server-2003, pagefile

anyone ever issue where changing the page file setting to system managed doesnt stick.  i change it, click ok, go back in, and its back to the defined values??  tried rebooting, same issue.  working with windows 2003 enterprise x32

Comment: OK - is there anything in the system event log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could happen if you have the setting defined in a GPO. Check that.

Comment: just confirmed that no GPO's are in place to modify any settings as it pertains to pagefile

Comment: i must be going crazy, cause now its working, time for a drink